# Scala upper bound for generic in field

Tags: scala

I have next field:

```
var operations = Map.empty[Long, _ <: Operation]
```

I want to get second generic parameter upper bound extends `Operation` class. When I'm doing like above I have error `unbound wildcard type`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `Map.empty[Long, Operation]`?

Comment: Yes I can do like that but is it possible to set upper bound as I've described?

Comment: `Operation` would be the upper bound in that case.  There's no need for the wildcard syntax in this scenario.

Comment: Ok thanks I guess it was a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to address the actual error at hand. As unnecessary as it is, it *will* work if you define it like this:

```
var operations: Map[Long, _ <: Operation] = Map.empty // Or some Map that conforms
```

The difference is that in the above code, we're saying `operations` has type `Map[Long, _ <: Operation]` -- which is a map from `Long` to *some type that we don't care about, so long as it is bounded above by `Operation`*. But `Map.empty` is a method call which expects some actual types to be supplied as type-parameters (or will be inferred as `Nothing`) and not an existential.

Of course, this is all unnecessary because `Map` is covariant over its second type parameter. That means that if you have some `Z` that is a sub-type of `Operation`, then `Map[Long, Z]` is a sub-type of `Map[Long, Operation]`.

Answer (score 2):

Map is defined as `trait Map[A, +B]`, so `Operation` is covariant - an upper-bound type in this example.

Just say `Map.empty[Long, Operation]`